# Backup files on webserver ! and ~

Tags: linux, apache, bash, vim

My LAMP web server renders backup files like these:

- `!index.php`
- `!~index.php`
- `bak.index.php`
- `Copy%20of%20index.php`

I tried deleting with `rm` but it cannot find the files.

Does this have something to do with bash or vim? How can this be fixed?

Comment: What is your error messages when you try deleting the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the characters (with a backslash) like so:

```
[ 09:55 jon@hozbox.com ~/t ]$ ll
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 jon people 0 Nov 27 09:55 !abc.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 jon people 0 Nov 27 09:55 ~qwerty.php
[ 09:55 jon@hozbox.com ~/t ]$ rm -v \!abc.html \~qwerty.php
removed '!abc.html'
removed '~qwerty.php'
[ 09:56 jon@hozbox.com ~/t ]$ ll
total 0
[ 09:56 jon@hozbox.com ~/t ]$
```

Comment: Running the rm -v \!index.php gave no such file. It looks like the file doesn't exist because [ find / -name \!index.php ] returns nothing, and updating /index.php with a die() command while going to /!index.php in the browser shows the updated index.php. Do you think this could be shortcuts?

Comment: What was occurring was index.php was being accessed at / and anything past it, like !index.php was being processed as a GET variable. I added some could to redirect to a 404 if there was a !, ~ or %20 in the uri

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that, other than the one suggested by chown, is write the filenames within `""`.

Example:

```
rm "!abc.html" "~qwerty.php"
```

Comment: the `rm "!abc.html"` might not work, depending on the shell setting for `histexpand`, which treats `!` as a special character (see section 'HISTORY EXPANSION' in `man bash`). That's why you have to use `rm \!abc.html` to be sure to delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the special treatment of the character `!`, use `set +H` in your shell to turn of history expansion. See section 'HISTORY EXPANSION' in man bash for more information.

Interestingly, I can delete files starting with `~` without having to escape the file names.